# Running nested sub test cases with Boost.Test

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

Simply said, can I achieve something like this with Boost.Test 1.58?

```cpp
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_test)
{
    auto context = construct_context();
    auto values = context.get_values();
    BOOST_REQUIRE(!values.empty()); // #1: breaks whole test case
    for(auto&& value: values)
        // Note: there's no 'BOOST_TEST_SCOPE' in Boost.Test, it's a pseudo-code
        BOOST_TEST_SCOPE("enum values") // Kind of "named nested scope", runs like '[&] ()` lambda
        {
            BOOST_CHECK(!value.empty()); // #2 Performs like normal check
            BOOST_REQUIRE_EQ(value.sub_value(), complex_computation(value)); // #3 Will break only to #4, not the whole case
        }; // #4 Where nested scope ends
    BOOST_CHECK(other_check(values)); // #5 will be run when loop ends -
                                      // because #3 will fail only BOOST_TEST_CASE block
}
```

**UPDATE**

I would prefer to avoid parametrized and data-driven tests. Both of them seem to require sophisticated reshuffle of my test code, with placing parts of it in different places, state handling and passing, instead of simple and linear procedural function.

Comment: achieve what? Is the code you show not working as expected?

Comment: Suites and fixtures do this. Are you coming from "Catch.hpp" background?

Comment: `BOOST_TEST_SCOPE` is a pseudo-macro, there's no such thing in Boost.Test. Updated question to make it clearer.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/test_case_generation.html

Comment: @sehe I'm limited to Boost 1.58. Also, I haven't found a way to construct such sub-suite right inside test case and run it right there. I simply need to fail part of test case, without all the suite/fixture/registration boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

The construct you have is similar to what test-suites are compared to test-cases. You have nested test-suites in boost.test, and there is no need for manual registration at all. You also have a powerful way to define [fixtures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures.html) for test-suites, including fixture [decoration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/test_org_reference/decorator_fixture.html) that can also be convenient. The test-case that is inside the test-suite can be a [parametrised](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/param_test.html) test-case.

I think all those constructs make the code clear and easily maintainable, but I obviously am biased.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use data-driven tests, I'd suggest just writing the loop, optionally using BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE to emit "meta" information so you can see where the loop starts:

```
for(auto&& value: values) {
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("enum values: " << value);
    BOOST_CHECK(!value.empty()); // #2 Performs like normal check
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQ(value.sub_value(), complex_computation(value)); 
}
```

Comment: This will halt whole test. What I need is to halt only single iteration, so that next iteration will run in any case.

Comment: "This will halt" - no. I get what you mean, but since you know that, just write the code surrounding it or maybe update boost etc.

Comment: `BOOST_REQUIRE_*` terminates execution of whole test case: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/reference.html

Comment: Note you can nest suites and suites can have fixtures

Comment: I'm aware. But this will require reshuffling test code in a complex way and writing all that boilerplate with suites, fixtures, manual registrations etc. I would prefer to keep my test case linear.

Comment: You say that as if you have working tests already. What makes you change frameworks? Also, a few well-aimed conditional save the day. Just don't REQUIRE the things you want CHECK-ed

Comment: Currently it's a simple runner of integration tests. What I see is that it conforms to patterns like BOOST_CHECK/BOOST_REQUIRE in many places. And I would like to leverage existing framework for faults checking. The whole project uses Boost.Test, and adding another test framework would be problematic.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting adding a framework. I was asking what framework you _had_ because you say you don't want to "change the code". (By the way, _What I see is that "it" (?) "conforms to" (?) patterns like BOOST_CHECK/BOOST_REQUIRE in "many places"(?)_ doesn't really mean much to me.) Nevermind. Perhaps someone else knows. Otherwise, you might still be able to use some of the hints

Comment: By "conforms to patterns" I mean there are 4 events in my code: informational message, warning, non-fatal error and fatal error. They roughly correspond to BOOST_MESSAGE, BOOST_WARN, BOOST_CHECK, BOOST_REQUIRE